# Go extension for Visual Studio Code add a go folder in my GOPATH or the current folder that i open

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode with the go extension so I created a new folder in my repo folder called `go-workspace` and change the `GOPATH` environment variable to that folder (`C:\Users\username\Documents\Repo`) but when I check the `GOPATH` detected by VScode using the `GO: Current GoPath` and the command returns `C:\Users\username\Documents\Repo\go-workspace\go`. I tried changing the folder but it keeps adding `\go` to the root folder, I also tried to create a new folder in a different path but it is still not working.

Comment: Use modules. See the official get started guide on golang.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you changed the `GOPATH` environment variable from the question yet. VSCode currently picks up the environment variables from either

1. Login shell (~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ... see your shell manual) if launched from the system default launcher, or
2. Inherit the environment from the terminal you invoke the VS Code application (`code`) even when you open a new vscode window from another vscode window,

(warning: the behavior I described above may change over time :-( )

and VS Code Go extension uses the environment variables VSCode picked up. So, please check if vscode itself picked up your setup.

The last resort is `"go.gopath"` as you figured out already.

Answer (score -1):

Ive fixed it by adding `"go.gopath"` in my settings.json in VScode

```json
"go.gopath":"path/to/prefered/gopath"
```